# How to use python requests with HTTPS

Tags: python, python-requests

I have this code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://mobile.twitter.com/session/new'

payload = {
       'username': 'username',
       'password': 'password',
       }
with requests.Session() as c:
    c.post(url, data=payload)
    r = c.get('https://mobile.twitter.com/account')
    print 'username' in r.content
```

The goal is to login to twitter mobile (I know there is an API, this is just for fun)... I already create a similar script using mechanize, and it works!

What's wrong with my code? Thanks

Comment: what are you getting as the response?

Comment: it won't logged in, so its jump back to /session/new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at login form hidden fields, you will find there `authenticity_token`, which is required. Also, your `url` was wrong.

Here is complete example:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'https://mobile.twitter.com/session'
    response = c.get(url)

    html = fromstring(response.content)
    payload = dict(html.forms[0].fields)

    payload.update({
       'username': '<username>@gmail.com',
       'password': '<password>',
    })

    print payload

    c.post(url, data=payload)
    r = c.get('https://mobile.twitter.com/account')
    print '<username>' in r.content
```